# How can i handle an array of checkbox using react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to handle an array of checkbox using react.js. Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
export default class Index extends Component{
 state = {
    myArray = ["Chair", "Spoon", "Cup"]
  }
 render(){
  return(
     {
       this.state.myArray.map(() => {
         <FormGroup>
           <Input
             name = {item}
             value = {item}
             checked = 
             onChange = 
         </FormGroup>
        })
     }
   )
 }
}
```

I am actually new to react and don't know how to handle or manipulate the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
export default class Index extends Component{
 state = {
    myArray = ["Chair", "Spoon", "Cup"],
    checked= [false,false,false]
  }
 handleChange=(index)=>{
   let newChecked=this.state.checked
       newChecked=!this.state.checked[index]
  this.setState({checked:newChecked})
} 
 render(){
  return(
     {
       this.state.myArray.map((item,index) => {
         <FormGroup>
           <Input
             name = {item}
             value = {item}
             checked = {this.state.checked[index]}
             onChange = {()=>this.handleChange(index)}
         </FormGroup>
        })
     }
   )
 }
}
```

The code has been provided but this isn't the approach, you cannot expect people to do your homework for you, try something out and then point out if  something is not working out.